# How do I show this parallel vector relationship?

Tags: vectors

I want to show that for two non-zero non-parallel vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, if $$x\vec{a} + y \vec b = 0$$ then $x = y = 0$.

This seems quite obvious but I cannot find an obvious way to prove it. I tried using a contrapositive proof instead.

Suppose if $x \neq  y \neq 0$. Then since components of the two vectors are also non-zero, then their resulant vector is also non-zero, thus proving the contrapositive. However, this seems too informal and I don't have a way to show the linear combination of 4 non-zero numbers (from $\vec a$, $x$, $\vec b$, $y$) will certainly give something non-zero as well, since they might as well cancel out.

Comment: You don’t need to look at components. Indeed, the vectors might not have “components” as such—what if your vectors are functions, for instance? What specifically does it mean for $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ to be non-parallel?

Answer (score 1):

This claim is not true.

For example, take $\vec{a}$ any vector and take $\vec{b}=\vec{a}$ (since any vector is clearly parallel to itself), then $x=1,y=-1$ satisfies the equation.

***Edit**: You're on the right track. What you want to show is that if $x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}=0$, and either $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$, then $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ must be parallel. Think about how their being parallel will relate to their components.*

Comment: Wouldn't that show two parallel vectors does not lead to $x=y=0$, which is a different claim? edit: I left out the non-parallel by mistake.

Comment: @mathworker123 Your claim, as I read it, was exactly that: "For two nonzero parallel vectors, if $x\vec{a} + y\vec{b} = 0$, then $x=y=0$," i.e., $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are parallel $\land x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}=0 \implies x=y=0$

Comment: @mathworker123 Just saw your edit.

Comment: Yes indeed your solution is correct for a parallel vector, my bad.

Comment: @mathworker123 Edited with a hint toward the proof in the nonparallel case.

Comment: What “components?” What if the vectors in question are polynomials or functions?

Comment: @amd I said "components" because mathworker123 mentioned "components" in the question. Therefore, I assume the vectors mathworker123 is wondering about are in finite-dimensional Euclidean space, and parallelism is determined by proportionality of the components. If we are in a more general context, then we'd have to be working with a different notion of parallelism, and amend the proof accordingly.